# Issue while converting .docx to pdf file in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf

I am working with conversion of .docx file to pdf file. docx file contains text, images, charts,. which has to be converted into pdf file. So i used the below code for my task. But, it shows **" Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 "**  I used 15 jars so for.

```
  try {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // 1) Load DOCX into XWPFDocument
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "/mnt/sdcard/HelloWorld.docx"));

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);

        // 2) Prepare Pdf options
        PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

        // 3) Convert XWPFDocument to Pdf
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                "/mnt/sdcard/HelloWorld.pdf"));

        PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);

        System.err.println("Generate pdf/HelloWorld.pdf with "
                + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I surfed google more, i got many suggestion like **project-->clean, editing eclipse.ini, change proguard in sdk,..** everything i tried, but none can help.
Can anybody help me or any solution ? Thanks.

Comment: finally the above coding run successfully, but there is warning ** " 02-20 08:07:45.924: E/dalvikvm(9028): Could not find class 'org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument', referenced from method com.example.sample.MainActivity.createPDF **
"